# handle filename with spaces in C

Tags: c, filenames

I'm developing a simple CLI program that permits 2 or more user (in the same LAN or across the internet) to share their files.

How it works:

1. open the terminal
2. run the program
3. drag and drop one or more files

My problem is: how can i make the program read the files that have spaces into their name?

Because if the user drag one file there is no problem (strtok until `\n`) but if the user drag into the terminal more than 1 file i have a **big** problem because i cannot use `strtok(input, ' ');` if the filename has spaces.

Example:

```
Files to share: /home/$USER/tryme /home/$USER/try me with space /home/$USER/file_ok
```

What can i do?

Comment: I think you need to add quotes to the paths.

Comment: the paths are quoted if i use the GNOME terminal but if i use the KDE one there are no quotes :(

Comment: Well then I think you have three options, write a gui to add files; add quotes manually or do as alex said below, add \ before spaces instead of quoutes around files.

Comment: oh dear :( i think i'll write a GUI...

Answer (score 0):

If the filename has spaces, then it should have a `\` before every space to escape them, otherwise it's expected they will be multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't drag and drop your files into the terminal because it take path "as is" so you need to modify the path strings after they're loaded into your program, Or just make a little interface (using gtk for example) and it'll be easier.

Comment: Haha yeah but it was an example, just une any interface lib

Comment: with C i don't have so much choice in addition to GTK :(

Comment: Just do a simple drag and drop system, i'll be better than a drag and drop terminal system. And if a terminal software don't use drag and drop ? Do you write the path ? X) Just do it.